# Switchmap returning single characters - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to return a value from a switchmap if a condition is met, but it's returning the console.log broken up in single characters. So if role comes back as Buyer, then it comes back as

```
console.log("RES");
console.log(res);
```

outputs

```
RES
B
RES
u
RES
y
RES
e
RES
r
```

How can I return the value intact from the `subscribe()`? I don't really understand why it breaks it up. I appreciate any help!

invite component.ts

```
...
   const linkExpiredDate = new Date(date);
          const invite = new SendInvite();
          invite.inviteEmail = form.value.email;
          invite.invitedBy = this.userId;
          invite.inviteLinkExpirationDate = linkExpiredDate;

          this.inviteService
            .sendInvite(invite)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
            .subscribe(
              res => {

                console.log("RES");
                console.log(res);

                this.timeout = this.toastr.success("Invite sent!", "", {
                  timeOut: 2000
                });

                this.invites.push({
                  inviteEmail: form.value.email,
                  invitedBy: this.userId,
                  inviteDate: Date.now()
                });

                this.dataSource.data = this.invites;
              },
              error => {

                console.log(error)
                this.timeout = this.toastr.warning(
                  "This user is already a member!",
                  "",
                  {
                    timeOut: 2000
                  }
                );
                return;
              }
            );
        }
```

invite service.ts

```
 sendInvite(inviteRequest: SendInvite) {
    console.log("INVITED BY" + inviteRequest.invitedBy);
    const invite: SendInvite = {
      id: null,
      inviteEmail: inviteRequest.inviteEmail,
      invitedBy: inviteRequest.invitedBy,
      inviteLinkExpirationDate: inviteRequest.inviteLinkExpirationDate
    };
    return this.validateEmail(invite.inviteEmail).pipe(
      switchMap(emails => {

        if (emails.message === "User found" && emails.role === "Artist") {
          this.toastr.warning("User already has a Seller Account", "", {
            timeOut: 6000
          });
          return emails.role;
        }
        if (emails.message === "User found" && emails.role === "Buyer") {
          this.toastr.warning("User already has a Buyer Account. Use different email or upgrade Buyer Account", "", {
            timeOut: 6000
          });
          return emails.role;
        } else {
          console.log("EMAIL MESSAGE " + emails.message);

          console.log("USER NOT FOUND!");
          return this.http.post<{
            messageId: string;
            inviteId: string;
            creator: string;
          }>(environment.azure_function_url + "/POST-Artist-Invites", invite);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're returning a `string` inside your switchMap function. A string is an array of characters. RxJS treats arrays as streams of events (sometimes with operators like `switchMap`, more specifically everywhere where you can pass `ObservableLike`). So what you get is a stream of character events that is merged into your outer observable. Thus your console output.

I guess what you probably want is to wrap your `emails.role` into an `of` operator, so you get `return of(emails.role)`.

`of` emits a single event with the value that you give it instead of trying to interpret the value as an Observable stream.